# linq to entities assigning join data to viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

Here is a linq query that assigns data to a viewmodel. It works great.

```
var data = (from C in db.CaseComplaints
                    where C.CasesID == caseid
                    select C.ComplaintCode).ToList().Select(x => new CaseComplaintsViewModel()
                        {
                            ComplaintCode = x.ComplaintCodeName,
                            ComplaintType = x.ComplaintType
                        }).ToList();
```

Here is code that tries to perform a join and assign the data to a viewmodel. It does not work. the code editor tells me that x does not have a method or definition for BranchName

```
var data = (from branch in db.Branches
                    join customer in db.Customers 
                    on branch.BranchID equals customer.BranchID
                    where customer.BranchID == bid
                    select branch.BranchName).ToList().Select(x => new CaseResponsibleBranchViewModel()
                        {
                            BranchName = x.BranchName
                        });
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already selected BranchName, which I suppose is a string, so there's no BranchName property of x:

```
var data = (from branch in db.Branches
                    join customer in db.Customers 
                    on branch.BranchID equals customer.BranchID
                    where customer.BranchID == bid
                    select branch.BranchName).ToList().Select(x => new CaseResponsibleBranchViewModel()
                        {
                            BranchName = x
                        });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am trying to assign the selected branch.BranchName to the BranchName property in the viewmodel CaseResponsibleBranchViewModel.

Comment: And my code does exactly that :) x is the value of branch.BranchName

Comment: Ah...ok, I missed that. Why would the two code snippets I provided be different in that one x has accessible properties and the other does not?

Comment: In the first code snippet you're getting whole entity in your query, in the second one you're getting just string value of one of the properties of the entity. You can rewrite the second one to select just branch, and then you'll be able to use the BranchName property. But if all you need is just this property, my version is more efficient, because it fetches values from just one column.

Comment: I and getting an error when passing the data resulting from the query back to the partial view: 

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.String,cummins_db.ViewModels.CaseResponsibleBranchViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'cummins_db.ViewModels.CaseResponsibleBranchViewModel'.

Not sure what that means.

Comment: If you need just one element of type CaseResponsibleBranchViewModel, you can use First extension method, preferably before you convert IQueryable to list, to avoid fetching of unneeded records from database. So, instead of calling ToList(), call First() (or FirstOrDefault() if you don't want to get an exception if the query returns no results), and from what First() will return you can create your CaseResponsibleBranchViewModel instance.